# Windows phone dispatcher timer issue

Tags: windows-phone-8, timer, dispatcher, app.xaml

I have a dispatcher timer in my windows phone app, issue is while user clicks on the center button (deactivated button) timer is stopping. I want to make this timer work when user again takes the app. I can save the stopping time in a isolated storage but getting confused while user again takes the app after the deactivated event occurs, timer getting stopped.

Basically i want a timer that runs when the application deactivating also.

Comment: Do you have any code you could show us?

Comment: post some code so that we can understand what you are trying to do exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have running timer when application is deactivated. But what you can do is to save the exact time when user close app by saving it to isolated storage settings in deactivate event. 
Then, when user activate app again, you need to get current time. Calculate how much time passed by and add it to your measured time variable.